# Page is not redirecting C# ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, response.redirect

Why doesn't my page redirect? The "Valid user" prompt pops up. But my page just does not redirect. What can be the issue?

```
protected void LoginButton_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (Page.IsValid)
{
User userLogin = new User();
userLogin.userId = this.txtUserName.Text.Trim();
userLogin.userPwd = this.txtPwd.Text.Trim();

string result = CommonFunctions.Check_ValidUser(userLogin);

if (result == "s")
{
Response.Write("<script>alert('" + "Valid user"+ "') ; location.href='Login.aspx'</script>");
Response.Redirect("DrugEntry.aspx",true);
}
else
{
string message = "We don't seem to have this user registered. Please try again.";
Response.Write("<script>alert('" + message + "') ; 
location.href='Login.aspx'</script>");
}
}
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug by putting a breakpoint at that line?

Comment: does your page exists at the correct location?

Comment: Is your "DrugEntry.aspx" page is in same directory OR is in folder?

Comment: @shree.pat18 I did. It executes that line. But does not redirect.

Comment: @ChiragAdhvaryu Redirection successful! You're right. It is in a different folder!Thanks!

Comment: @divinediu : glad to help you. I have posted it as an answer. don't forget to accept it and upvote it. so that it may help other developers facing the same issue.

Comment: Does your alert work if the user is not registered? You are constructing a string with an inverted comma in it and then passing the string to a javascript alert.

Comment: @MartinSmellworse yes you are right javascript alert not allow inverted comma which gives you critical error in javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your code is correct.

Make sure that your page is in the same directory. If it is not in the same directory that use it as mentioned in below sample :

```
Response.Redirect("[Directory Name]/DrugEntry.aspx",true);
```

Comment: Presumably trying to indicate where the directory name should go.

Comment: @Bharadwaj [Directory Name] means [folder name] in which page is located